# viewbox SVG attribute causes graphs to become spaced very far apart

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, svg, d3.js

I have multiple D3 graphs on a cordova/phonegap page and want to have them scale to fit the horizontal / vertical screens.  Adding attributes of "Viewbox" & "presereAspectRatio" did that great as long as I commented out the earlier width & hight attributes.

The graphs are just defined on the page as:

```
   <div id="graph1"></div>
   <div id="graph2"></div>
   <div id="graph3"></div>
   etc....
```

and work fine with the static attr's of "width" & "height"

But when I add the attribute "viewbox" they scale wonderfully, but are now spaced about ~15cm apart from each other causing you to have to scroll down the phone a long time to see them.

If I comment out the "viewbox" & "preserveAspectRatio" & uncomment the original static "width" & "height" attributes the graphs appear on the screen one after another as before.  But they are static.  I'm not sure what aspect within or outside each  could be affected by this.

Below is the code I'm using for the select aspect, etc.

```
    var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 35,
    left: 40
},
    width = 475 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 205 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    var svg = d3.select("#graph1")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox","0 0 475 205")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")

//        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
//        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave off the `width` and `height`, they get set to 100%, which means that the height will be 100% of your viewport. That means extra space gets added to the bottom of your svg. You can test this by creating a `<rect>` that is the size of your viewBox, and placing a border on the svg element.

[HERE](http://jsbin.com/berew/1/edit?html,css,output) is an example. As you can see, there is extra space that is outside of the viewBox (not covered by the rect) that is part of the svg element.

Unfortunately, you're probably going to need to use a script to resize the svg's. You can create a function to set the height attribute based on the width of the container (perhaps the body element in your case) and the ratio of the height and width in your viewBox. Here's one way to do that:

```
function resizeAll() {
  d3.selectAll('svg').call(scaleSvg);
}

function scaleSvg(sel) {
  sel.each(function() {
    // split the viewbox into its component parts
    var vbArray = d3.select(this).attr('viewBox').split(' ');
    // find the ratio of height to width
    var heightWidthRatio = +vbArray[3] / +vbArray[2];
    // get the width of the body (or you could use some other container)
    var w = document.body.offsetWidth;
    // set the width and height of the element
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', w * heightWidthRatio);
  });
}
```

Then you would simply call `resizeAll()` when the page loads, and when the window is resized.

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/giliqa/1/edit?js,output) is an example.

Comment: Thanks jsanley!  That fixed 90% of it ;)   However I have one last challenge that on either the phone or emulator selecting the view graph page link still is spaced in the original wide positioning.  However when I turn the phone to horizontal position (resize) it corrects it & also corrects it when I return back to a vertical screen.  I have the "window.onresize = resizeAll;  & resizeAll();" in the ondocument load area & also on the button calling the graph view w/ the function in the javascript called.  It's not picking it up the first time.  Any thoughts on that would be great ;)

Comment: Are you saying you click a link to display the graph? If so, you might want to use that click handler to call the function. One nice thing about the way the example is set up is that you can call `scaleSvg()` on any selection. You could use the click handler to scale only the graph that is being displayed on click by first creating it and then calling `d3.select(yourGraphSVG).call(scaleSvg)`